# Select statement in straight up sql command execution in c#

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I have this t sql query that looks something like this

`"select top 1 V_someview.column1 from dbo.someview join dbo.sometable on someview blah blah where blah blah"`

You get the point, a query returning one value of type `int.`
So I just need to use get that `int` from this query in c#.
I need to use either `ExecuteStoreQuery` or `ExecuteStoreCommand`.

So far I tried:

```
var returnedInt = db.ExecuteStoreQuery<int>(queryText);
var data = db.executeStoreCommand(queryText, new object[0])
```

btw I could use entity framework but not sure how it works when there is joins etc.

Found out this works int returnedInt = db.ExecuteStoreQuery(queryText).First();

Comment: So, what doesn't work about it? Are you getting an error message?

Comment: This is slightly confusing. `ExecuteStoreQuery` is (I assume) from Entity Framework, but then you say "I could use EF". Are you using it or not?

Comment: @DanielKelley Ya my bad thought they were different. I thought those methods were standard .net lib.

Comment: I just tried one thing that on my ExecuteStoreQuery I added .first() that returned the integer I was looking for. I will close this out.

Comment: @DoodleKana: I think it's a good question. You don't have to delete it.

Comment: @Cory Ok, I chose yours as the answer.

Answer (score 1):

The method `ExecuteStoreQuery<T>` returns a sequence of `T` . Grab the `First` or `FirstOrDefault` from that sequence:

```
var returnedInt = db.ExecuteStoreQuery<int>(queryText).FirstOrDefault();
```